# Geolocation based query not working in mongo from php

Tags: php, mongodb, geolocation

I have a mongo collection called a city with the following json

```
{
  "city_name": "Amesbury",
  "lat": "42.8583925",
  "lng": "-70.9300376",
  "geo_coords": [-70.9300376,42.8583925]
}
```

As you can see this collection has a geolocation of amesbury. Now i am trying to fetch this using php and i used the following code.

```
$collection = $this->mongodb->city;
        $collection->ensureIndex(array('geo_coords' => '2d'));

        $radiusMiles = 500000; //get all results within 5 miles
        $radiusOfEarth = 3956; //avg radius of earth in miles

        $cursor = $collection->find(
            array('geo_coords' =>
                array('$within' =>
                    array('$centerSphere' =>
                        array(
                            array($lng, $lat), $radiusMiles/$radiusOfEarth
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

To this code i pass the longitude and latitude of boston as message argument and i expect the query to fetch amesbury as result as both are neighbouring cities and is definitely with in 500000 miles of each other.

But my query is not returning any results. What can the issue be?

Comment: have you tried it from mongo javascript shell?

Answer (score 0):

The geo coordinates aren't in the correct format. It should be, ideally, an array of two numbers:

```
"geo": [-70.9300376, 42.8583925]
```

Please read the full documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Comment: Tried changing the coordinates to the correct format and still no luck, any other ideas?

Comment: Just read the documentation http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-SphericalExample , your range is a bit too big as well it seems.